# Can I Run Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04 on an ATI XPress 200 graphics card?

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, upgrade, ati

I have a acer aspire t650 pc with a pentium 4 processor and a ati xpress 200 grafics card.
**Does anybody knows if I can update ubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 and to 13.04 and if so which driver do I need to install?**
I am unsure because there is already no support for radeon 2xxx and 4xxx cards

Answer (score -2):

you would have to install all of them and just split up your hard drive by portioning it. Then every time you turn on you computer it will ask you which one you would like to run with.

Comment: The question is not about dual booting several Ubuntu versions. Please read the whole question again.

Comment: ok but might there be a problem concerning my grafics card and the driver version?

Comment: I found a program (http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/install-ati-amd-catalyst-drivers-in.html) on google and I installed and runned it and i sais that i can install the amd catalyst 13.4 and the 13.6 beta driver. Should i take the risk and install it?

Answer (score -2):

yes, you can, now I'm working on ubuntu 13.04 PC that it's processor Pentium 4 3Ghz and 1GB RAM

however, it's not any good, slow and laggy, i dont know how much of RAM you have but i suggest 2GB or more and you may feel like your PC is slow because of the CPU, but not seriously

i use it for internet, chat, and some hacking and all works fine, as i told you, the RAM is very important, i had to put 1GB swap file (RAM ON DISK)

mine, if i run ubuntu software center only, the memory will went up to 700MB of RAM used and 600MB of swap file is used

firefox uses +100MB more

about graphic card you must install drivers to make it work for

[Instructions For Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/129200/53498)

[Instructions For Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/286775/21195)

Comment: I found a program (noobslab.com/2013/04/install-ati-amd-catalyst-drivers-in.html) on google and I installed and runned it and i sais that i can install the amd catalyst 13.4 and the 13.6 beta driver. Should i take the risk and install it?

Comment: @Yousefs The question is about graphics card support. Not about memory usage. I don't see what your post has to do with the question of the OP.

Comment: sorry didnt notice that, he must install drivers to make it work

for ubuntu 12.10 :

http://askubuntu.com/a/129200/53498

For ubuntu 13.04 :

http://askubuntu.com/a/286775/21195